# Javascript find a string in a multidimensional array and return that array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like

```
    var schedule = [
{date:'9/21/2011',mId:1,title:'Faith, Fraud and Minimum Wage',director:'George Mihalka',startTime:'9:20 PM',length:'91',genre:'Drama',movieType:'Faith, Fraud and Minimum Wage',trailer:'iVs5VL2kH8s',synopsis:'Halifax actor, dramatist and screenwriter Josh MacDonald’s hit play <i>Halo</i> has finally hit the big screen, courtesy of <i>My Bloody Valentine</i> director George Mihalka and legendary producer Colin Neale.\nA tragicomic tale of faith in a skeptical age, <i>Faith, Fraud and Minimum Wage</i> is based on real-life incidents in Nova Scotia that generated international headlines. In the economically depressed town of Nately, a young atheist maverick named Casey discovers the image of Jesus on the outside wall of her coffee-shop workplace. As outside interest builds and Nately finally makes it on the map, Casey’s own strained domestic situation boils to a climax.\nClever, moving and surprisingly respectful, <i>Faith, Fraud and Minimum Wage</i> features sparkling performances from the likes of Picnicface’s Andrew Bush (as the town priest), Callum Keith Rennie (as the dad) and Martha MacIsaac in the central role of Casey.',location:'Parklane',movieTime:'Fri, Sep 3, 7PM',moviePic:'../movies/faithfraudminimumwage/1.png'},
{date:'9/21/2011',mId:2,title:'Mind The Gap',director:'Aaron Au',startTime:'7:00 PM',length:'7',genre:'Drama',movieType:'CBC Atlantic Shorts Gala',trailer:'hbLgszfXTAY',synopsis:'Halifax actor, dramatist and screenwriter Josh MacDonald’s hit play <i>Halo</i> has finally hit the big screen, courtesy of <i>My Bloody Valentine</i> director George Mihalka and legendary producer Colin Neale.\nA tragicomic tale of faith in a skeptical age, <i>Faith, Fraud and Minimum Wage</i> is based on real-life incidents in Nova Scotia that generated international headlines. In the economically depressed town of Nately, a young atheist maverick named Casey discovers the image of Jesus on the outside wall of her coffee-shop workplace. As outside interest builds and Nately finally makes it on the map, Casey’s own strained domestic situation boils to a climax.\nClever, moving and surprisingly respectful, <i>Faith, Fraud and Minimum Wage</i> features sparkling performances from the likes of Picnicface’s Andrew Bush (as the town priest), Callum Keith Rennie (as the dad) and Martha MacIsaac in the central role of Casey.',location:'Oxford Theatre',movieTime:'Fri, Sep 8, 7PM',moviePic:'../movies/faithfraudminimumwage/1.png'},
{date:'9/24/2011',mId:2,title:'Mind The Gap',director:'Aaron Au',startTime:'7:00 PM',length:'7',genre:'Drama',movieType:'CBC Atlantic Shorts Gala',trailer:'hbLgszfXTAY',synopsis:'Halifax actor, dramatist and screenwriter Josh MacDonald’s hit play <i>Halo</i> has finally hit the big screen, courtesy of <i>My Bloody Valentine</i> director George Mihalka and legendary producer Colin Neale.\nA tragicomic tale of faith in a skeptical age, <i>Faith, Fraud and Minimum Wage</i> is based on real-life incidents in Nova Scotia that generated international headlines. In the economically depressed town of Nately, a young atheist maverick named Casey discovers the image of Jesus on the outside wall of her coffee-shop workplace. As outside interest builds and Nately finally makes it on the map, Casey’s own strained domestic situation boils to a climax.\nClever, moving and surprisingly respectful, <i>Faith, Fraud and Minimum Wage</i> features sparkling performances from the likes of Picnicface’s Andrew Bush (as the town priest), Callum Keith Rennie (as the dad) and Martha MacIsaac in the central role of Casey.',location:'Parklane',movieTime:'Fri, Sep 12, 7PM',moviePic:'../movies/faithfraudminimumwage/1.png'},

];
```

and I have a movie listing, and I want to see if the current movie listings mId is equal to any other mId's in the array schedule, if so return them in an array so I can loop through them and display the other results.

I am a bit confused with how to do this? I assumed you use `array.filter` but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array.filter should work. Try the following code:

```
var filtered = schedule.filter(function(val) {
  return val['mId'] != searchMid;
});
```

where searchMid is the mid you are searching for.

Comment: Where should the value I am search for go? Lets say I am searching for mId 2 in the array. Should it be 2 != val; or?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Forgot to include that. I'll go edit my answer.